# Meteor + MongoDB: How to get nested data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I'm new to Meteor and trying to figure out this issue I have.

I'm trying to load data from the Lessons collection based on the route being passed.  e.g if /courses/level1/lesson1/1a is passed then show data

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Am I on the right path or is there a better way of doing this?

**Collection**

```
{
  "_id": "YSgr3fvjpEBn7ncRa",
  "courseId": "level1",
  "lesson": [
    {
      "lessonId": "lesson1",
      "freeLesson": true,
      "title": "Lesson 1",
      "eachLesson": [
        {
          "eachLessonId": "1a",
          "title": "This is (masculine)",
          "video": "839843"
        },
        {
          "eachLessonId": "1b",
          "title": "That is (masculine)",
          "video": "839843"
        },
        {
          "eachLessonId": "1c",
          "title": "This is (feminine)",
          "video": "839843"
        },
        {
          "eachLessonId": "1d",
          "title": "That is (feminine)",
          "video": "839843"
        },
        {
          "eachLessonId": "1e",
          "title": "Getting to know you",
          "video": "839843"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Routes**

```
 Router.route("courses/:courseId/:lessonId/:eachLessonId", {
  path:"/courses/:courseId/:lessonId/:eachLessonId",
  layoutTemplate: "layoutLessons",
  template:"lessons",
  onBeforeAction:function(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    if (currentUser) {
      Session.set('courseId', this.params.courseId);
      Session.set('lessonId', this.params.lessonId);
      Session.set('eachLessonId', this.params.eachLessonId);
      this.next();
     } else {
       Router.go('/')
     }
  },
});
```

**Template helper**

```
Template.lessons.onCreated(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('listLessons');
});


Template.lessons.helpers({
  currentLesson: function() {
    var currentLesson = Session.get('eachLessonId');
    return Lessons.find({"lesson.eachLesson.eachLessonId" : currentLesson});
  },
});
```

**HTML**

```
{{#each currentLesson}}
  {{title}}
  {{video}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing `courseId`, `lessonId` and `eachLessonId` as `Session` values, you could use the [Iron Router's](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) **[`waitOn`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-waiton-option)** and **[`data`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data)** option.

For example, you could rewrite your route as follows:

```
Router.route('/courses/:courseId/:lessonId/:eachLessonId', {
  name: 'lessons',
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutLessons',
  template: 'lessons',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    let currentUser = Meteor.user();
    if (currentUser) this.next();
    else Router.go('/');
  },
  data: function() {
    var doc = Lessons.findOne({
      "courseId": this.params.courseId,
      "lesson.lessonId": this.params.lessonId,
      "lesson.eachLesson.eachLessonId": this.params.eachLessonId
    });
    if (doc) {
      var lesson = {};
      var lessonId = this.params.eachLessonId;
      _.each(doc.lesson, function(i) {
        lesson = _.find(i.eachLesson, function(j) {
          return j.eachLessonId == lessonId;
        });
      });
      return lesson;
    }
    return {};
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('lesson', this.params.courseId, this.params.lessonId, this.params.eachLessonId)
    ];
  }
});
```

This should set the data context to the requested `eachLesson` object. However, you may consider setting the data context to a document in the `Lessons` collection and then just picking certain `eachLesson` objects. In addition, you should create a publish function which returns just the requested `Lessons` document and not all of them, like you probably do now in your `listLessons` publication. You can pass all IDs as arguments to the corresponding publish function.

Comment: It works! :-) The only issue is that it is continuously loading after pulling in the data. So if I change waitOn to subscriptions: it loads the data and the loading text is still there and if I leave waitOn it loads no data and just keeps loading.

Comment: @user1400803 Okay, that's not good. Could you please check the server/client log?

Comment: @user1400803 Could you please post your publish function?

Comment: Using handlebars which calls {{title}} and {{video}} and I have Meteor.publish("Lessons", function(){
  return Lessons.find();
}); in the server.

Comment: I've removed the waitOn and it works without loading. I guess because all lessons are already published it loads them on call. A better way would be as you said, load the lessons on demand with a publish function.